# Wordpress site using Woocommerce Won't Display Buy Button

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have recently created a test site using woocommerce and for some obscure reason I am unable to buy a product from it as the buy button just won't appear, the theme im using is xmarket. I have been through google and tried everything from sku codes to variable prices and payment methods but just can't fathom it out.

Does anyone know of a conflict with the theme or experienced something simular as I am not sure where to look next so any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few things you'll want to check.
Do you mean the "Add to Cart" button? If you want a external link, be sure to set that up as External/Affiliate product.
Do you have a price setup for the product? Make sure you have that set.
Do you have a Payment Gateway setup?
That should lead you in the right direction hopefully.

Comment: Yeah thanks for replying, I have already checked all of the above, what I am actually missing is the button to actually buy anything here is the test URL http://symon.wp-example.tk  if you wouldnt mind seeing if I have missed anything. the checkout pages spits out this at the bottom Fatal error: Call to undefined method WC_Shipping::get_available_shipping_methods() in /var/sites/s/symon.wp-example.tk/public_html/wp-content/themes/xmarket/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php on line 8  I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing woocommerce but its exactly the same result

Comment: Oh I see, it's the actual "Check Out" button that you are missing. Try disabling all of your plugins and see if that works. Don't deactivate WooCommerce itself though. If that still does not resolve the issue, try another theme that has WooCommerce support for testing and see if the button appears then.

Comment: Tried that as well, I think woocommerce has updated quite dramatically from what i have been reading and the theme needs an update.  cheers for your help but it looks like I gotta find another way around it